# Map tensor values to 1 or 0 by treshold

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor like `t=[[0.2],[0.8],[0.4]]`.

and want to map every `value>0.8` to `1` and to `0` if below that treshold.

I tried it with `tf.where`, but it does not work.

```
tf.where(t>0.8,tf.ones(t),tf.zeros_like(t))
```

The code:

```
self.temp_sim = tf.where(self.predictions>0.8,tf.ones(self.predictions),tf.zeros_like(self.predictions))
```

The error:

```
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 1700, in ones
    output = fill(shape, constant(one, dtype=dtype), name=name)
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 3468, in fill
    "Fill", dims=dims, value=value, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 609, in _apply_op_helper
    param_name=input_name)
  File "C:\Users\\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 60, in _SatisfiesTypeConstraint
    ", ".join(dtypes.as_dtype(x).name for x in allowed_list)))
TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'dims' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64
```

It is not working to format it as code!!

Comment: Just do `tf.cast(t > 0.8, tf.int32)` or `tf.cast(t > 0.8, tf.float32)` (or the data type that you want to have). The error in your code is that `tf.ones(t)` should be `tf.ones_like(t)`.

Comment: Thanks! it works with ! But wheres the difference?

Comment: Well both things are equivalent in the end, but `tf.cast` is just "converting" the true/false values into numbers and with `tf.where` selects from two other tensors, so I'd say casting is "cheaper" to run.